# How to suppress zero bars in a barplot?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have this barplot:

```
barplot(table(
  factor(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 10), levels=seq(0, 10, 1))
  ))
```

In this barplot, bar outlines are drawn where the y-value is 0, resulting in a line:

[image: Image of a barplot with lines for frequencies of 0]

I would like there to be no line, but a gap:

[image: Image of a barplot without lines for frequencies of 0]

How can I suppress these lines?

*Note: I don't want to suppress x values where y is 0! I want there to be a gap!*

Comment: use `border = NA` to suppress all borders or if you want to keep the ones for the non zero bars, you can pass a vector to `border`, eg, `border = ifelse(t == 0, 'transparent', 'black')` where t is the table of counts

Comment: @rawr I get `Error in t == 0 : comparison (==) is possible only for atomic and list types`. —— Forget that, of course I had to replace `t` with my table. Now it works. Would you like to post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: the edit below has essentially the same answer

Comment: To me these gaps rather look like errata and, thus, might confuse the reader. I would definitely stick with zero values still showing the border which is perfectly fine to me, particularly since they are also of different color.

Comment: @jay.sf I agree, but my question is taken out of context and the complete graph is quite different than the sample code you see here.

Comment: @user23211738 Fair enough, ty for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option how to do it is split the code, here is an example:

```
# Create a table
df <- table(factor(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 10), levels = seq(0, 10, 1)))

# Create a barplot
barplot(df[df != 0])
```

[image]

But to remove the button lines, you can remove border lines:

```
barplot(table(factor(data, levels = seq(0, 10, 1))), border = ifelse(table(data) != 0, "white", NA))
```

[image]